# Как сделать затухающую строку на конусообразной фигуре?

Tags: html, svg, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь создать файл svg с кругом, имеющий сужающуюся границу,  что означает, что ширина границы будет самой толстой (скажем, 20 пикселей) с исходным цветом и будет самой тонкой (скажем, 3 пикселя) на противоположной стороне, где цвет поблек. Мне удалось создать круг с выцветанием цвета с помощью  градиента, но я изо всех сил пытаюсь понять, как изменить ширину границы.

Вот код, который у меня есть, который я создал в Photoshop и экспортировал в svg.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 20px;
        stroke: url(#a);
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="255.5" y1="240" x2="255.5" y2="51" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(96,0,0,1)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(96,0,0,.1)"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle class="cls-1" cx="255.5" cy="255.5" r="184.5"/>
</svg>
```

Вот изображение того, что я пытаюсь сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Извините, еще один вопрос.
Я пытаюсь создать иконку, чтобы у неё было четыре таких кружков разного цвета, один из которых плавно переходил в верх, как показано на рисунке, другой - в нижнюю, а два других - по бокам.
Я буду очень признателен, если вы также покажете мне, как вращать эти окружности.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [svg circle tapered fading stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68333595/7394871) от участника  [@user3659161](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3659161/user3659161).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68333595/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Я бы нарисовал круг побольше с отверстием внутри. В данном случае я использую маску. Вы также можете нарисовать контурную дорожку. В обоих случаях вы используете градиент как заливку, а не как обводку.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: url(#a);
      }      
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="255.5" y1="240" x2="255.5" y2="51" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="rgba(96,0,0,1)"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="rgba(96,0,0,.1)"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m">
      <circle id="c1" cx="255.5" cy="255.5" r="184.5" fill="white" />
      <circle fill="black" cx="255.5" cy="245.5" r="164.5"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle  cx="255.5" cy="255.5" r="184.5" class="cls-1" mask="url(#m)" />  
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68333836/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**Цитата из вопроса:**

> Извините, еще один вопрос. Я пытаюсь создать иконку, чтобы у неё было
> четыре таких кружков разного цвета, один из которых плавно переходил в
> верх, как показано на рисунке, другой - в нижнюю, а два других - по
> бокам. Я буду очень признателен, если вы также покажете мне, как
> вращать эти окружности.

Для решения используются два кольца расположенные друг над другом.

Первая окружность вращается по часовой стрелке

```
<animateTransform 
  attributeName="transform" 
   type="rotate" 
    values="0 150 150;360 150 150" 
     begin="svg1.click" 
      dur="10s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" 
      />
```

Вторая окружность вращается против часовой стрелки.
Так как верхней окружности задан параметр непрозрачности `fill-opacity:0.5;`
то при вращении и полупрозрачности верхней окружности создается эффект изменения результирующей толщины границы.

К обоим окружностям добавлена анимация градиента:

```
 <animate 
     attributeName="stop-color" 
     dur="1.5s" 
     values="red;yellow;red"
     repeatCount="indefinite" 
/>
```

Текст `Click me`    добавлен для демонстрации и его можно удалить.

*Ниже приведен полный код:*

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

svg {
background:black;
}

#path1 {
fill:url(#gradl);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:1;
}
#path2 {
fill:url(#grad2);
stroke:none;
fill-opacity:0.5;
}
#crc1 {
stroke:none;
fill:black;
}
#txt1 {
fill:url(#grad2);

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 300 300" > 
<defs>
<linearGradient id="gradl" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="0.9"> 
      <animate 
         attributeName="stop-color" 
         dur="1.5s" 
         values="red;yellow;red"
         repeatCount="indefinite" 
      />    
    </stop>          
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow">
       <animate  
         attributeName="stop-color" 
         dur="1.5s" 
         values="yellow;red;yellow" repeatCount="indefinite" 
         /> 
       </stop>                      
            
 </linearGradient> 
        
    <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="lime"> 
          <animate 
             attributeName="stop-color" 
             dur="1.5s" 
             values="lime;purple;lime"
             repeatCount="indefinite" 
           />   
        </stop>          
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="purple">
       <animate  
         attributeName="stop-color" 
         dur="1.5s" 
         values="purple;lime;purple" repeatCount="indefinite" 
         /> 
       </stop>                      
        
    </linearGradient> 
        
</defs>
    <path id="path1" d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" > 
     <animateTransform 
      attributeName="transform" 
       type="rotate" 
        values="0 150 150;360 150 150" 
         begin="svg1.click" 
          dur="10s"
          repeatCount="indefinite" 
          /> 
    </path>

<path id="path2" transform="rotate(45 150 150)" 
  d="M71.9 78.4C90.8 58.1 122.9 50.7 150.6 51.5c26.2 0.7 54.9 10.5 72.8 29.7 16.9 18.1 22.9 45.8 23.4 70.6 0.5 25.1-3.2 54.4-20.7 72.4-18.5 19.1-49.4 24.5-76 24.3-25.4-0.2-54.4-6.3-72.4-24.3C59.5 205.8 53.9 176.5 53 150.8 52.2 125.9 55 96.7 71.9 78.4Z" >
 <animateTransform 
  attributeName="transform" 
   type="rotate" 
    values="360 148 148;0 148 148" 
    begin="svg1.click" 
     dur="10s"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</path>
<circle id="crc1" cx="150" cy="150" r="90" /> 
 <text id="txt1" x="80" y="160" font-size="36" font-weight="700" > Click me </text>
</svg>  
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334740/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>